# correctly debug in XCode 4.4

Tags: macos, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

on XCode 4.2 when a breakpoint is active while debugging, if I put my mouse pointer over a variable name (into the source code) and a yellow tooltip appears and let me able to view the variabile value (for base type like int, float, and other).

Yesterday I update XCode to 4.4 (for testing my apps on iOS 5.1.1) but when the game stops into a breakpoint, and I move my mouse pointer over a variable, no yellow tooltip was showed.

I think this "fast debugging" is too important, because a programmer, else, for view class fields, need to:
1. Selecting "Local" instead "Auto"
2. Open 'self' object
3. Searching the variabile to view value
this is very slow ...

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply need to clean your build folder and have Xcode re-index the project. Hold down Option while selecting the Clean option from the menu, it'll change into Clean Build Folder.

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D, I've tried but no result :(
It's an old cocos2d project, I think version 0.99, maybe I must change compiler or another stuff? thank you